# Sending dynamically added value inside click

Tags: javascript, angular

Well `(click)="PageNumberChanged(pageNumber-1)"` this works perfectly fine but `(click)="PageNumberChanged(pageNumber+1)"` adds value as string not as a number
 if `pageNumber` is 10 result should be `11` but it returns `101`
what I tried:-

1. `(click)="PageNumberChanged('{{pageNumber+1}}')"`
2. `(click)="PageNumberChanged(eval(pageNumber+1))"`
3. `(click)="PageNumberChanged('pageNumber+1')"`

   @Input() pageNumber:number;

am getting `pageNumber` from other component and made sure sending a number as value.

I know I can create a function with two arguments and can get the work done, but the issue I want to understand the mistake, so that I can improve further working on angular,

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the logic inside the controller function,

```
$scope.PageNumberChanged = function(pageNum){
   var newPageNum = pageNum + 1;
}
```

or you can directly pass it as

```
 <button ng-click="PageNumberChanged(pageNum +1 )"> Change </button>
```

**NOTE**

Also you should replace **`(click)`** with **`ng-click`**, there is not (click) with angularjs, it's only with angular

**EDIT**

Since OP's question is with Angular5, it should work as below,

```
(click)="PageNumberChanged(pageNumber+1)"
```

The reason for your issue is  your variable is a String, when you add + on it it will be doing a concatenation

**[DEMO WITH ANGULAR5](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjpsft?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: as mentioned in the question it could be done by passing two arguments to the function

Comment: @phpdroid check the 2nd way

Comment: second method u replaced (click) by ng-click if am not wrong?

Comment: you should use ng-click only always with angularjs

Comment: @phpdroid dude! then you have tagged the question wrongly it should be angular. then click should work as above

Comment: @phpdroid check the updated edit, that should be the answer

Comment: do u find any difference between your sol.  and my question ?

Comment: yes indeed! there is no quotes in the solution i provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164295/discussion-between-phpdroid-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 0):

If your pageNum variable is a String, everything you "+" in it, will be converted to string. You can make sure it's a number by converting it before summing, like this: Number(pageNum) + 1

```js
console.log(typeof "1");
console.log(typeof Number("1"))
```

Comment: _co.Number is not a function

Comment: check on snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
(click)="PageNumberChanged(pageNumber+1)"
```

to

```
 (click)="PageNumberChanged(pageNumber+'+1')"
```

and `eval` in component.ts is the only way I could make it work. 
still couldn't find the genuine issue in my code.